# Do any languages form plural pronouns by adding a suffix to the singular form?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number, list-of-languages, plurality

Are there languages whose plural pronouns ('we', 'they', etc.) are formed from singular pronouns ('I', 'he', etc.) plus a plural marker?

For example, if English were such a language, instead of "we" we would say "Is" (the pronoun 'I' + the plural suffix -s), "hes" to mean "they", etc.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and it would be hard to pick a single "best" answer.

Comment: @Javid, I guess you're right (in fact, it already happened), but the question is on-topic, isn't it?

Comment: @JMCF125 Yes, it is.

Comment: @JMCF125 - Sure, but isn't the litmus test on the Stack Exchange sites whether a single best answer can be selected? For example, "what is the most useful programming book" is technically on-topic and a valuable/useful question to many people, but that question has been marked as too broad in Stack Overflow because you can't select a single answer. There are numerous other examples. I'll leave it at that to avoid further discussion in the comments.

Comment: @JavidJamae If you want to discuss that further, you can open a Meta question or a chat room. I don't think anybody would be against that.

Comment: Have you consider accepting a answer? I'd suggest mine (which is more straightforward in my biased opinion `:)`) or any other with many examples and plenty of explanation, such as robert's or PElliot's.  Although I did upvote almost everything in here, so not even I'd be sure which one to choose...

Answer (score 12):

As already said, Japanese works this way:

```
私      +   達 = we
watashi   tachi
```

But the same happens in Chinese as well:

```
我 + 们 = we
wo  men
```

The first portion of both is the standard way to say "I" (we'll ignore other versions for the sake of this answer). The second is a plural marker.

Comment: That's not quite true. Japanese (and I'd imagine Chinese as well) do not actually have a true singular/plural. -tachi and -ra are what's called the associative plural - they indicate the accompaniment of others in addition to the base nominal (etymology: 'tachi' means 'companion'). Most pronouns and proper nouns are inherently singular, and must take this suffix when referring to plurals; in contrast, common nouns have no number, and rarely take such a suffix.

Comment: The distinction between "plural" and "accompaniment of others" is that a true plural is homogenous - having multiple instances of the same noun. "accompaniment of others" is heterogeneous - potentially containing things of fundamentally different types.

Comment: @JustinOlbrantz The OP was referring to personal pronouns in their question, so the part about common nouns you specified is not included in this question and, as far as I see, your comment doesn't really apply to my answer even if I understand what you meant to highlight.

Comment: Note that etymologically 私 is a noun and not pronoun though. Morphologically and syntactically Modern Japanese nouns are identical to pronouns. Old/Middle Japanese did have われ (ware) and なれ (nare) though, which behaved distinctly from nouns, most notably by taking on irregular declensions (stem drops the -re before some suffixes). They actually do add the usual OJ plural -ra: われら (warera), なれら (narera)

Comment: The Chinese example might be invalid though, since Chinese is isolating and 们 is a particle that gets to stick on any noun phrase. -ら in Japanese is a clitic though, which may be borderline suffix. AFAIK it attaches rigidly to nouns and never to entire noun phrases with things coming between the noun and the -ra.

Comment: Anyway, "我們"，"你們" and "他/她/它們" seem to be the only candidates for plural **pronouns** in modern standard Chinese.

Comment: Ancient Chinese does **not** distinguish between singular and plural pronouns. After around Han dynasty (2nd century BC), a plural case may be indicated by adding **concrete** words with meaning "the kind of", "several", etc. For example "吾->吾輩", "我->我屬", "彼->彼等". "們" is observed to emerge around the 10th century (Song dynasty).

Answer (score 12):

Some varieties of English have plural personal pronouns that are composed in roughly the way you're asking.

### Southern US English

[*you'all*/ *y'all*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all) is composed of the 2nd p. singular pronoun + plural marker *all*. Because there is now a separate 2nd p. plural pronoun *you* tends to be restricted to singular reference.

I understand the other comments as saying that Japanese *tachi* in *watashi-tachi* is a plural marker that it is also used in other circumstances as a plural marker. *you'all* doesn't meet that definition because it's not grammaticalised as a morphological plural marker. But it marks plurality lexically and *could* in the future be grammaticalised as a plural marker.

### Tok Pisin

Tok Pisin is an English-based creole (more specifically: English is the lexifier language) spoken in Papua New Guinea. The morpheme *pela* (from English *fellow*) argueably works as a plural (or not-singular) marker in the [pronoun system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tok_Pisin):

- 1st (exclusive) singular: *mi*
- 1st (exclusive) plural: *mipela*
- 2nd singular: *yu*
- 2nd plural: *yupela*

The Dual is marked in the following way:

- 1st (exclusive) dual: *mitupela*
- 2nd dual: *yutupela*

This is why I said *pela* might be interpreted as not-singular because it's also used in the dual (and trial where it exists).

3rd person dual conforms to the system: *tupela*

But 3rd personal singular and plural have suppletive forms: *em* and *ol*

Again, as far as I know *pela* is not used as a plural marker otherwise. But the meaning of the pronouns is still compositional in that there is a person morpheme (e.g. *mi*), a dual morpheme (*tu*), and a non-singular morpheme (*pela*) that combine to form the various pronouns.

Comment: The Southern US English case is a great example. We can tell this is genuinely a 2nd person plural pronoun, and not just a contraction of the pronoun + floating quantifier, since, apparently, the following is fine: a) "All y'all get in the car".

Comment: @PElliott, wouldn't that a) be redundant?

Comment: I don't see why. The first 'all' is a quantifier, the second is a grammaticalised plural marker. It's no more redundant than saying 'all of them'.

Comment: I started thinking of creoles before I got to this answer. I looked at English-based creole pronouns a few years ago when I was interested in dual/inclusive/exclusive and found that all the ones I looked at home similar but distinct systems to Tok Pisin. Sorry no details though ...

Comment: @PElliott indeed, "All (of) y'all" refers to each person individually, whereas "y'all" refers to the group as such.

Comment: Surely Northern Ireland's *youse* is a more obvious plural form. (Here in the midlands, I say *ye*.)

Answer (score 10):

[yous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yous)

> This regional term is predominantly used in Scotland and Ireland and throughout Australia, as well as overseas areas of previous Irish emigration e.g. some parts of the US (Boston, MA and Philadelphia, PA) and northern Nova Scotia and Lanark Ontario/Canada and South Auckland, New Zealand. It also occurs in Scouse (usually spelled "yous" as above, instead of "youse" a more American variant).
>
> *Noun.* Plural form of you.

Comment: I always used to see it spelled *youse* in Australia too.

Comment: How do you know that this is formed from *you* plus the plural *-s*?

Comment: @curiousdannii. [YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/youse) quotes *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, 5th edition as giving the origin of *youse* as **you + –s**.

Answer (score 8):

*Edit*: I had almost forgotten about the existence of **WALS**. Chapter 35 gives an overview of plurality in independent personal pronouns: [Chapter Plurality in Independent Personal Pronouns.](http://wals.info/chapter/35)

It looks like the category most relevant to your question is type 8 (person stem with a nominal plural affix). If you look at the map on WALS, you can see 19 type 8 languages listed, many of which have been mentioned here, e.g. Chinese, Japanese, Southern US English. Type 3 (person-number affixes) and type 7 (person stem with a pronominal number affix) might also be of interest to you, as they show some morphological complexity in the expression of number in the pronominal system.

Interestingly, it looks like it's far more common *not* to have a morphologically transparent pronominal system, like English. The morphologically transparent pronominal systems are in a small minority.

---

Several meso-melanesian languages have morphologically complex pronominal systems, including number marking on plural pronouns. One example:

**Babatana**

- 1sg exclusive = *ra*
- 1dual exc. = *raru*
- 1pl exc. = *rami*

Kubokota, another meso-melanesian language is especially interesting, in that the plural form is suppletive, but the dual and trial forms are morphologically complex, with the plural form as a stem:

**Kubokota**

- 1sg. exc. = *ara*
- 1pl. exc = *yami*
- 1dual exc = *yami-kori*
- 1trial exc = *yami-kue*

['Nominal Number in Meso-Melanesian' (Palmer, 2012)](http://cslipublications.stanford.edu/LFG/17/papers/lfg12palmer.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

One of these languages is Thai, except it's not a suffix, but a prefix:

คุณ `[kʰun]` *you* (singular, formal) - พวกคุณ `[pʰûːək kʰun]` *you all* (plural, formal)
เธอ `[tʰɤː]` *you* (singular, informal) - พวกเธอ `[pʰûːək tʰɤː]` *you all* (plural, informal)
เขา `[kʰáu]` *he/she* - พวกเขา `[pʰûːək kʰáu]` *they*

Note, this does not apply 1st person: ผม versus เรา or พวกเรา

Comment: *thou* is singular informal; *you* is formal.

Answer (score 6):

Another language that does this is Nhanda, a Pama-Nyungan language of Western Australia. Nhanda has a productive plural suffix '-nu', which is used to form plurals of both nouns and pronouns, as follows (only showing subject forms):

- *ngayi* = 1sg 'I' - *ngayinu* = 1pl 'we'
- *ngini* = 2sg 'you.sg' - *ngininu* = 2pl 'you.pl'
- *ala* = 3sg 'he/she/it'; *alanu* = 3pl 'they'

For more detail see:
Blevins, Juliette. 2001. *Nhanda: an Aboriginal language of Western Australia*. Honolulu: University of Hawai'i Press.

Answer (score 6):

In Persian (a.k.a. Farsi) pronouns are built with suffixes:

man => me, maha => we

shoma => you (formal), shomaha => you all (plural formal)

an => he/she/it, anha => they

Answer (score 5):

**Hungarian**

```
ő  = he/she (genderless) 
ők = they (also genderless)
```

Note that in Hungarian, the suffix *-k* is generally used for plural for all words, not just in this case.

The basic case has only the third person obeying this rule, the other two are exceptions. However, in other cases, most (or all, I didn't really count) obey this rule, with minor variations, but still ending in "k":

```
nekem -> nekünk (for me -> for us)
neked -> nektek (for you, singular -> for you, plural)
neki -> nekik (for him/her -> for them)

velem -> velünk (with me -> with us)
veled -> veletek (with you, singular -> with you, plural)
vele -> velük (with him/her -> with them)
```

Other examples, listing only one person, (but all persons have this rule)

```
tőlem -> tőlünk (from me -> from us)
enyém -> mienk (mine -> ours) derived from (én=me, mi=we)
```

etc.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention ön -> önök.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to go around the world to find examples. In Portuguese and French, all plural personal pronouns end in "s". Check below:

```
English       French   Portuguese

I             je       eu
you           tu       tu
he            il       ele
she           elle     ela
it            -        -
we            nous     nós
you           vous     vós
they (masc)   ils      eles
they (fem)    elles    elas
```

Notice for "il/ele" and "elle/ela" the plurals are precisely what you were looking for. Plus, they're formed as in English (they're all related languages, so it's no big deal). Interesting that when I saw your question I thought "well, that's interesting", until I tested if it worked in Portuguese: then the answer was obvious.

As these answers have shown, this is far from uncommon, even appearing in English non-standard forms. I guess if you knew some other languages it would help, don't you think?

I noticed no one directly answered your question, and although it is clear what all of us mean, I always like a direct answer: **yes, there are such languages**.

Answer (score 4):

Quechua has completely regular plural second- and third-person pronouns:

- 1sg: *ñoqa*
- 2sg: *qam*
- 3sg: *pay*
- 1pl excl.: *ñoqayku*
- 1pl incl.: *ñoqanchik*
- 2pl: *qamkuna*
- 3pl: *paykuna*

*cf*.:

- “man”: *runa*
- “men”: *runakuna*
- “woman”: *warmi*
- “women”: *warmikuna*

The plural suffix -*kuna* is not mandatory if context suffices.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are the plural affixes also used to mark plurality in the nominal domain generally, or are they unique to the pronominal paradigm?

Comment: I updated the entry with examples of “man” and “woman.”

Answer (score 3):

My first language, [Tamil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language), has the "gal" suffix in its formal form, and the "ga" or "nga" suffix in the colloquial form.

```
Me - Naan    
Us - Naangal (formal)/Naanga (colloquial)

You - Nee  
You (plural) - Neengal (formal)/Neenga (colloquial)

He/She (polite) - Avar (formal)  
They (polite) - Avargal (formal)

It - Adhu   
They (neuter) - Adhugal (formal - rare)/Adhunga (colloquial)

He (impolite) - Avan   
They (masculine, impolite) - Avanuga (colloquial only)

She (impolite) - Aval   
They (feminine, impolite) - Avaluga (colloquial only)
```

The same suffixes apply for nouns also, though I just realized the curious fact that most of the time we leave out the plural marker in colloquial Tamil. `10 naay irundhadhu` (10 dog was there) is at least as frequently used as `10 naaynga irundhadhu` (10 dogs were there). Optional grammatical number!

```
Vehicle - Vandi 
Vehicles - Vandigal (formal)/Vandinga (colloquial)

Dog - Naay
Dogs - Naaygal (formal)/Naaynga (colloquial)
```

Comment: Good contribution! I think it would help readers if you pointed out exactly what the plural morpheme is and whether it is also used in other circumstances as a plural marker (such as on nouns). Also, is it colloquial or formal Tamil you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

In standard Arabic,

- *Ant* = You mascline sg
- *Anti* = you feminine sg
- *Antuma* = you dual
- *Antum* = you mascline pl
- *Antunna* = you feminine pl

Comment: Good example! Isn't the 3rd person masculine singular *anta*, though, in Modern Standard Arabic?

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for since the suffixes -uma, -um, -unna aren't used to form duals or plurals generally in Arabic, only in these pronouns (I believe).

Answer (score 2):

**Spanish:**

*ella (she) => ellas (they)*

**Finnish:**

*tämä (this evident) => nämä (these evident)*

*tuo  (that evident) => nuo (those evident)*

*se (that, non-evident) => ne (those, non-evident)*

The marker *N* is said by [Michael Fortescue](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Language_Relations_Across_the_Bering_Str.html?id=Su_xVd0gTOcC&redir_esc=y) to be the remnant of common Nostratic plural -n, present in modern Semito-Hamitic and Germanic languages (and also in a rare form of plural in Komi: *pi* => *pian* (*son => sons*). Cf. also Komi *pi* with English *boy*, Finnish *poika*, Swedish *pojke*, all the three being of presumably unknown etymology).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the glossing a little? I'm not familiar with 'evident' in this context. What is it taken to mean?

Comment: Evident means 'conveying the meaning of evidentiality'.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality

Comment: What is the meaning of d'oh? I have no native language, so some English expressions are obscure to me.

Comment: See this video for an extended explanation of the meaning of "d'oh" :-) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DdeLUA0Fms

I don't quite understand what you mean when you say you have no native language. Were you a feral child or something? I suspect you understand *native language* to mean something different to me.

Comment: By 'native language' I mean a language which determines cognitive patterns of a person. I have no such a language. And I make occasional grammatical mistakes in any of the languages I speak more or less fluently.

Comment: The question of 'what is a native speaker' was answered a while ago here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1914/2328. It's not a black & white distinction, but the conventional use in linguistics is to mean the language(s) you acquire during the critical period. You're free to use the term however you like of course, but that's what it means within the field.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia suggests that Japanese is such a language. For example the pronoun *watashi* "I" becomes *watashi-tachi* "we"

Comment: Japanese has already been mentioned in the first answer.

Comment: @PElliott To be honest, Danger posted before I did. I posted because I wanted to mention Chinese as well and add some other details.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Apologies Danger.

Answer (score 1):

Aymara

```
naya    -naka    we (exclusive)
juma    -naka    you (pl.)
jupa    -naka    they
jiwasa  -naka    we (inclusive, more than 2)
```

*Nayanaka* is obligatorily contracted to *nänaka* though.

Comment: What language familiar is Aymara from?

Comment: @curiousdannii Aymaran languages (=Aymara, Jaqaru, and Kawki)

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the Tamil:

avai (அவை) is the plural of athu used in formal speech and in writing, not athugaL.

The plural of both avan and avaL is avanga in every speech community I have ever heard (and is also used to refer respectfully to individuals).  I would not be so bold as to say Avaluga is never used but I would need more details before I accept it as an attested variation.

Answer (score 0):

In **Turkish**, `-ler` and `-lar` are the plural suffixes. Both have the exact same meaning and function; the one whose voice is most fitting comes at the end of the word.

```
               |    Normal Form    |     Polite Form
-----------------------------------------------------
I              |    Ben            |     Biz
You (sig.)     |    Sen            |     Siz
He, She, It    |    O              |     Onlar⁽¹⁾
We             |    Biz            |     Bizler⁽²⁾
You (pul.)     |    Siz            |     Sizler⁽²⁾
They           |    Onlar⁽¹⁾       |     Onlar⁽¹⁾
```

⁽¹⁾ `Onlar` is the plural form of `o`, made by adding the plural suffix `-lar`. The auxiliary letter `n` between is just for making it read easier; It would had been difficult to read if it was written as `olar`.
⁽²⁾ These are made by simply adding the plural suffix `-ler`.